# Do I need to create static routes for my home network?

Tags: wireless-networking, routing, static-routes

```
50.x.x.x assigned by Frontier
192.168.1.1  Actiontec (FiosModem/Router)
  192.168.1.2  Voip
  192.168.1.3  DLINK/DIR615 (WirelesRouter)

192.168.1.3  assigned by Actiontec
192.168.2.1  DLINK DIR615 (Hardwired to Actiontec)
  192.168.2.194 Android
  192.168.2.195 Vista-PC1
  192.168.2.196 WIN7-PC2
  192.168.2.197 Linksys-1 WRT54G/DDWRT(WirelessClient)
  192.168.2.198 Linksys-2 WRT54G/DDWRT(WirelessClient)
  192.168.2.199 DSi

192.168.2.197 assigned by DLINK
192.168.3.1  Linksys-1 WRT54G/DDWRT
  192.168.3.100 Vista-PC3

192.168.2.198 assigned by DLINK
192.168.4.1  Linksys-2 WRT54G/DDWRT
  192.168.4.100 Ubuntu-PC4
```

Above is my current setup.

All PCs have Internet access.

PC3 and PC4 cannot see each other and PC1/PC2 cannot see PC3/PC4.

Do I need static routes between PC3 & PC4, PC1/PC2 & PC3/PC4? If how do I create the static routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable all of the extra NAT-ing that you have going on. Set the DD-WRT clients up as [wireless bridges](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Bridge), not wireless clients. This will cause them to transparently join the network, instead of firewalling the computers connected to them from the rest of the network.

Comment: +1 to Darth Android's answer. @SZU, don't do double (or triple, or quadruple) NAT, unless you really know what you're doing and know why you want it. This network description is a complete nightmare. Only do NAT on the device at the head of your network (usually the integrated broadband modem / home gateway / Wi-Fi access point that came bundled with your broadband service).

Comment: @Darth Android, thank you for your extremely quick and useful response.  I was trying to get 2 PCs connected via LinksysWRT54G/DDWRT to communicate with each other and I thought there was static routing issue involved since they didn't communicate even though they all have internet access. I will try your suggestion of setting up the DD-WRT clients up as wireless bridges when I get home this evening.  I would have left out the network the DLINK/DIR615 but I couldn't get the 2 LinksysWRT54Gs to link with the Actiontec Router

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see any need for this tripple NAT setup if you do *not* want to separate the clients, but if you want to keep it this way, you would need to add routes on the LAN interface of your DIR-615.

```
Network          Gateway
192.168.3.0/24   192.168.2.197
192.168.4.0/24   192.168.2.198
```

The /24 suffix is just a guess and would equal a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0. Adjust network address/suffix if needed.

Since there are many different versions of the DIR-615 I cannot explain the exact steps for your specific version. Just check the manual on this topic if you are unable to locate the routing setup.

Conclusion: Bridging would be simpler to setup and probably has no disadvantage in your scenario.